# Welche Anrede wird unter Internetgemeindemitgliedern bei Begegnungen im echten Leben am besten verwendet?

Tags: salutation

Ich habe ein Paar Mal Mitglieder aus einem deutschen Internetforum, wo wir immer einander duzen, „in Wirklichkeit“ auf Messen usw. getroffen. Ich war dann recht unsicher welche Anrede am besten wäre. Wir haben ja schon zu einander „Du“ geschrieben, weil das *im Forum* die Etikette ist, aber, wenn man sich eigentlich nicht kennt, kommt es mir Auge vor Auge mit dem anderen ein wenig aufdringlich vor.

Habt ihr hier Meinungen, Empfehlungen oder sogar Erfahrungen dazu?

Comment: Es kommt drauf an... Aber sehr, sehr wahrscheinlich Duzen.

Comment: Sehr wahrscheinlich duzen. Ich sieze auch im Internet, auch wenn viele nicht höflich genug sind, es mir gleichzutun. Ich sehe nicht, weshalb man da unterscheiden sollte.

Comment: Wenn man sich schriftlich duzt, gibt es meistens keinen Grund mündlich zu siezen. Es sei denn, der "Mikkie" vom Forum ist ein 70-jähriger Professor und man fühlt sich einfach unwohl, so eine ehrwürdige Person zu duzen.

Comment: @Ludi: Da in Foren, Chaträumen etc. entgegengesetzt zum sonstigen Sprachgebrauch "Sie" tendenziell unhöflicher wirkt als "du", ist die Annahme, es gebe da möglicherweise eine Unterscheidung, nicht ganz unberechtigt.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper ich lasse mich überall gern siezen und sieze überall. Allerdings sehe ich darüber hinweg, wenn man mich duzt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich kann nur für mich persönlich sprechen:

Ich bin 51 Jahre alt und hasse es sehr, wenn ich z.B. bei Ikea einfach so geduzt werde. (Genau aus diesem Grund kaufe ich dort nicht mehr ein. Das gilt auch für andere Geschäfte wo ich ungefragt geduzt werde.) Ich ziehe also in der persönlichen Begegnung mit Unbekannten ganz entschieden das »Sie« vor, freue mich aber wenn mir das Du-Wort angeboten wird, und biete es anderen auch gerne an. Aber einen fremden Erwachsenen einfach so mit »Du« anzureden, halte ich für außerordentlich unhöflich.

Im Internet hingegen stört es mich gar nicht geduzt zu werden. Dort ist es Standard geduzt zu werden, und auch ich duze in der schriftlichen Kommunikation in Internetforen eigentlich jeden. In E-Mails hingegen wähle ich jene Form, die ich auch in einem normalen Brief oder im persönlichen Gespräch verwenden würde.

Wenn ich nun jemanden persönlich treffe, den ich bisher nur aus Internetforen kannte, dann prallen diese beiden Einstellungen natürlich aufeinander. Meine persönliche Lösung:

Schon bei der Begrüßung spreche ich diesen Umstand an, und biete meinem gegenüber sozusagen »ganz offiziell« das Du-Wort an, vorausgesetzt das steht mir gemäß den üblichen Anstandsregeln überhaupt zu (die Frau bietet dem Mann das Du-Wort an, der Ältere dem Jüngeren, der mit höherem Status, z.B. der eigene Vorgesetzte, dem mit niedrigerem). Das nimmt zumindest mir (und meist auch meinem Gesprächspartner) die Unsicherheit.

Falls es nicht an mir ist, das Du-Wort anzubieten, hoffe ich, dass der andere das macht. Wenn das nicht passiert, versuche ich Formulierungen zu vermeiden, in denen ich meinen Gesprächspartner direkt in der zweiten Person ansprechen muss, und warte ab, welche Höflichkeitsform mein Gesprächspartner wählt und schließe mich dann seiner Wahl an.

Falls in dieser Situation mein Gegenüber ebenfalls die Du/Sie-Entscheidung hinauszögert (das fällt ja irgendwann auf, wenn man der direkte Anrede permanent aus dem weg geht), dann wähle ich irgendwann dann das *Sie*.

Comment: Diese Situation ist also auch für Muttersprachlige nicht total einfach und selbstverständlich.  Nächstes Mal werde ich also so tun, wie ich es vorher gemacht habe, das Duzen vorschlagen, wenn es an mir ankommen sollte.

Answer (score 2):

Je nach Forum/Chatraum siezt oder duzt man sich.

Gerade in branchenspezifischen Foren siezt man sich meistens.

Wenn du die selbe Form im echten Leben nimmst, wird dir das ganz sicher niemand übel nehmen. Schlimmer ist es dann die Form zu wechseln, das erachten viele Menschen als unfreundlich.

Wenn dir jemand beispielsweise das "du" anbietet, du aber ihn nach einiger Zeit nur noch siezt, wird er denken, dass du nichts mit ihm zu tun haben möchtest oder sauer auf ihn bist. Wenn man sich einmal geeinigt hat, was durch das Chatten entstanden ist, sollte man dabei bleiben.

Answer (score 2):

Für mich kommt es auf die **Umstände des Zusammentreffens** an.

Wenn ich mich mit jemandem, den ich aus einem Forum kenne, aufgrund dieser Forenbekanntschaft zu einem persönlichen Treffen **verabrede**, dann rede ich diese Person so an, wie es auch im Forum üblich ist, weil wir dann auch im realen Leben gewissermaßen "im Forum" sind. Dies muss keine direkte Verabredung mit einer bestimmten einzelnen Person sein, auch ein **User-Treffen** ist für mich eine Verlängerung des Forums ins wirkliche Leben, und ich duze dann alle dort Anwesenden. Dasselbe gilt, wenn das Forum der virtuelle Ableger einer nicht-virtuellen Gemeinschaft ist, wie z.B. das Forum einer Interessensgemeinschaft oder eines Vereins. Auch hier sehe ich die Umgangsformen im Forum als Spiegel der Umgangsformen im wirklichen Leben an und duze oder sieze real wie im Netz, auch wenn ich die Personen zuerst über das Netz kennengelernt habe.

Wenn ich derselben Person aber nur **zufällig** in einer Situation begegne, die mit dem Forum nichts zu tun hat, dann wähle ich die dieser Situation angemessene Anrede (siehe dazu die Antwort von Hubert Schölnast).